# Display data from props in table

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display some data in a table but I'm not having any luck. Below is the object I am working with and my component with the table. 
When I attempt to access the keys and values of data I keep getting an error saying Data is not defined.

Object:

```
{"exampleReducer":{"exampleData":{"exampleData":{"data":{"userId":1,"id":1,"title":"delectus aut autem","completed":false}
```

Component:

```
class App extends Component {

  onClick = () => {
    this.props.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}><h1>Hello World</h1></button>
        {JSON.stringify(this.props.stateData)}
        <table className="table table-striped table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>User ID</th>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th className="text-right">Completed</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              {Object.keys(this.props.stateData).map(value => <td>{value.userId}</td>)}
              {Object.values(this.props.stateData).map(value => <td>{value.id}</td>)}
              {Object.values(this.props.stateData).map(value => <td>{value.title}</td>)}
              {Object.values(this.props.stateData).map(value => <td>{value.completed}</td>)}
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    stateData: state
  }
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchData: () => dispatch(fetchData())
  }
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

Comment: Looks like you got a bit mixed up on your data order when you went from a dynamic table to a fixed table. Inside your body, you should map over the collection of things you want as rows (maybe `Object.values(this.props.stateData.exampleData)`?) and put each of those in a `<tr>`. Then for each `item` in that collection make a td for each column in that row you want, and extract the data from the `item`... But your data doesn't look like a collection of similar objects, more like a single deeply nested object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplified and workable solution

```
    class App extends Component {

      onClick = () => {
         this.props.fetchData();
      }

      render() {
          const { stateData } = this.props;
          return (
             <div>
                 <button onClick={this.onClick}><h1>Hello World</h1></button>
                 {stateData && JSON.stringify(stateData)}
               <table className="table table-striped table-hover">
                   <thead>
                         <tr>
                             <th>User ID</th>
                             <th>ID</th>
                             <th>Title</th>
                             <th className="text-right">Completed</th>
                            </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                          {stateData && ( <tr>
                               <td>{stateData.exampleReducer.exampleData.exampleData.data.userId}</td>
                           <td>{stateData.exampleReducer.exampleData.exampleData.data.id}</td>
                    <td>{stateData.exampleReducer.exampleData.exampleData.data.title}</td>
                 <td>{stateData.exampleReducer.exampleData.exampleData.data.completed}</td>

                  </tr>)}
              </tbody>
           </table>
         </div>
          );
       }
     }
```

What happens in your case is that stateData will be undefined on initial render but you are doing iteration on an undefined value and that’s why you get that error.

Answer (score 1):

Completely agreed with solution provided by Hemadri Dasari,
But
 {stateData.exampleReducer.exampleData.exampleData.data}
is a long path to extract data .

It's a good practise to  define these paths is mapStateToProps function as ,

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    stateData: 
state.exampleReducer.exampleData.exampleData.data
  }

So that you can directly use stateData to access properties of object.

Hope this helps,

Cheers !!